# Get the register that do not have some values in different rows

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table:

| name | Conf |
| --- | --- |
| First | 101 |
| First | 301 |
| First | 701 |
| Second | 501 |
| Second | 601 |
| Second | 701 |

I want to get all names that do not have CONF = 101, 201 or 301 with Postgres. In this case, only *Second*.
I tried with **IN**, **NOT IN** and **ANY**. But never get the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
select distinct src.name
from the_table as src
where not exists (
  select 1
  from the_table as other
  where other.name = src.name
    and other.conf in (101,201,301))
```